# PsychoPy reopen window

Tags: python, oop, window, psychopy

I programmed a dot probe paradigm using the Standalone PsychoPy v1.80.03. After the dot probe I need a modified task that looks identical to the dot probe. I therefore pass the dot probe object in the 2nd task's constructor to re-use the window and the stimulus containers bound to this window.

Before the 2nd task starts I, however, need to input some information (e.g. the condition) using a `gui.DlgFromDict`. With the window from the dot probe still in fullscreen, the Dialog Box cannot be reached.

I tried to change the fullscreen to false by `dotProbe.window.fullscr = False` followed by a `dotProbe.window.flip()` but once the window is instantiated, changing this attribute doesn't seem to have an effect.

Closing the window with `dotProbe.window.close()` makes the Dialog accessible but there is no function that opens the window again to proceed in the 2nd task. Of course I could just construct a new window but as I said I need the identical setup with the stimuli at the exact same positions and all other parameters alike. Copying all parameters from one script to another to "manually" ensure them to look identical is undesired - as are workarounds like providing the input for the 2nd task prior to the dot probe since the scripts should be able be run independently (if no dot probe object is provided in the constructor, a new one is created to provide the default look).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to close the window: that actually destroys the entire object, along with all of its stimuli and other attributes.

A solution to a similar problem was posted here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/psychopy-users/zq2E12vnYiI/6mXirJMlq3cJ

According to Jan Kramer there (and a subsequent improvement from jashubbard here: https://discourse.psychopy.org/t/bug-user-defined-gui-does-not-display-in-full-screen-on-mac-osx/2214/3), I think you want to use something like:

```
win.winHandle.minimize() # minimise the PsychoPy window
win.winHandle.set_fullscreen(False) # disable fullscreen
win.flip() # redraw the (minimised) window
```

This will hide the window away rather than closing it. Then restore it with:

```
win.winHandle.maximize()
win.winHandle.set_fullscreen(True) 
win.winHandle.activate()
win.flip()
```

Comment: This works pretty well, thank you! The winHandle object is not documented in the [API](http://www.psychopy.org/api/visual/window.html). Is there a chance to find these gems directly without asking someone who happens to know? ;)

Comment: Hi Mario, the docs can always be improved: volunteers greatly encouraged :-) But we are also hoping that questions and answers here on StackOverflow will provide readily Googleable answers in a way that is less cryptic for beginners than burrowing through the API docs or though long threads on the mailing list archive. So thanks for marking your question as "answered" and providing feedback: it helps people in the future who will have the same query.

Comment: I see. Thanks again! As soon as I got my reputation to 15 I will also mark your answer as useful :P